# Apache me muestra el codigo de php en vez de ejecutarlo

Tags: php, ubuntu, apache2, vagrant

Buenas vengo con esta pregunta que he tratado de buscar solución pero no puedo encontrarla tengo poca experiencia en `linux` y estoy aprendiendo, la versión donde tengo todo instalado es `ubuntu 16` estoy usando `vagrant` creando un servidor con maquinas virtuales.

ya instale todo ya que verifique ingresando la **`IP`** del servidor de la maquina virtual y me indica que el servidor esta bien

pero al ejecutar un archivo 
php el navegador en vez de mostrar lo que procesa php me muestra el código del archivo

y es la función **`phpinfo()`**

Comment: Revisa que el servicio que utilizas para levantar php (por ejemplo Apache), esté levantado.

Comment: hace falta decirle a apache como interpretar archivos php, generalmente es activando el módulo `mod_php` pero tambien lo podes configurar via proxy `ProxyPassMatch ^/(.*\.php(/.*)?)$ ...`  esto se hace en la etapa de provision o al elegir el box que estas levantando

Comment: ¿Probastes poner el codigo con los simbolos de codigo php:
O sea <?php phpinfo() ; ?>

Comment: hola mis estimados

Comment: no se como activar ese modulo de apache que me indicas

Comment: si probe usando las etiquetas <?php ?> como tambien <? ?> pero nada

Comment: como podria activar ese modulo alo Malbarez

Comment: si me ayudan la respuesta la va a encontrar otros usuarios ya que indiga por google pero no encontre una solucion que me resolviera el problema

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Prueba con:

```
sudo apt-get install libapache2-mod-php
```

Comment: preguntastes la version de PHP?  ademas debes agregar el modulo y reiniciar apache2 para tu ejemplo, completa la respuesta y da una explicacion, elabora una buena respuesta y la comunidad te premiara

Comment: te invito a leer [como responder](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)

Comment: okay voy a probar y comento mis resultados

Comment: yeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeee

Comment: funcionoooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooo

Comment: gracias amigo aprendi algo nuevo hoy

Answer (score 0):

Edita el archivo /etc/apache2/mods-enabled/php8.1.conf
Busca esta linea:
php_admin_flag engine Off
y cambiala por esta:
php_admin_flag engine On